# Edittext does not retain text

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, extends

I have one Activity (Categories.java) that extends an other Activity (BaseMenuActivity.java)

At the first Activity when i press an Action bar button (R.id.search) i call a Dialog which has an EditText (mEdit) that is at the second Activity (BaseMenuActivity.java).

My first Activity (Categories.java) is declared like this:

```
public class Categories extends BaseMenuActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
..............
}
```

The second Activity (BaseMenuActivity.java) is the following:

```
abstract class BaseMenuActivity extends Activity {

private Context context;

/// Creates the menu items
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_list, menu);
return true;
}

//Handles item selections from preference menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

context=this;

if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Categories.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}

if(item.getItemId()==R.id.search){

    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builderbanner = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderbanner.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null));
    builderbanner.setTitle("Search.......");
    //.setMessage(".........................")
    builderbanner.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        EditText mEdit;
        String searchWord;

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Dialog f=(Dialog) dialog;

            mEdit= (EditText)f.findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
            searchWord= mEdit.getText().toString();

            Intent i= new Intent(context, Love_db.class);
            Bundle extracase = new Bundle();
            extracase.putString("label", "SEARCH RESULTS");
            extracase.putString("searchWord", searchWord);
            extracase.putInt("index", 99);
            i.putExtras(extracase);
            startActivity(i);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builderbanner.create();
    builderbanner.show();
    return true;
}

if(item.getItemId()==R.id.mine){
    //startActivity(new Intent(this, SendMyMantinada.class));
    return true;
}

if(item.getItemId()==R.id.prefs){
    //startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

I want to ask why this EditText (mEdit) does not retain its value when pressing back button or why is the dialog disappeared when i change orientation.
And what should i do to solve that problem because i want to retain the text i entered at EditText mEdit.

Thank you

Comment: Read the lifecycle of the android activity and you need to add add code in onconfigurationchanged() when orientation changes.when you click back button try using finish()

Comment: Sorry i do not understand what i should do

Answer (score 0):

[LifeCycle of Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

When you move from one activity to another activity, all values has been deleted which to be assigned.

Solution for your question : 
**you have to store value of edittext in shared preference or database.**